# HIP binary kernel not found

Tags: gpu, gpu-module

I just got a MINISFORUM Venus UM790 Pro Mini PC AMD Ryzen 9 7940HS up to 5.2 GHz 64GB DDR5 1TB SSD with AMD Radeon 780M. I enabled HIP in system settings and selected the 780M GPU. I selected GPU compute in render settings. However, when I try to go to viewport rendered mode or F12 to render scene, I get the following error:

HIP binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (11.0) not found.

Am I forgetting to set something in my settings? Is my version of Blender (4.0.2; just downloaded) incorrect? Has Blender not yet provided the kernel for this AMD GPU? Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/are-mini-pcs-strong-enough-for-blender/1479720) thread on blenderartists.org and the [Blender manual section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#gpu-rendering) on GPU rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue. Cycles needs a quite specific minimal version for AMD's drivers.

> Minimum driver versions:
>
> - Windows: Radeon Software 21.12.1 or Radeon PRO Software 21.Q4
> - Linux: Radeon Software 22.10 or ROCm 5.3
>
> **Source:** [Render - Cycles - GPU Rendering -- Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#hip-amd)